# Cannot compare String in Java and String from SQL Database

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I am currently coding in JSP pages with java. The problem i am having is that i cannot get strings `CNIC` to be compared with `CNICc`. I am basically comparing to not have more than two entries with the same CNIC(social security number). I am not that good in coding so kindly elaborate what the problem would be.

```
 String uname=request.getParameter("UName");
        String name=request.getParameter("Name");
        String age=request.getParameter("Age");
        String address=request.getParameter("Address");
        String CNIC=request.getParameter("CNIC");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql1","root", "");
       Statement s= c.createStatement();
       PreparedStatement ps=c.prepareStatement("insert into hitchhikerdetails(Uname,Name,Age,Address,CNIC) values(?,?,?,?,?)" );

       ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("select * from hitchhikerdetails");
       ps.setString(1, uname);
       ps.setString(2, name);
       ps.setString(3, age);
       ps.setString(4, address);
       ps.setString(5, CNIC);
       String CNICc;

      rs.beforeFirst();
       while(rs.next())
       {    
           CNICc=rs.getString(5);
           //out.println(CNIC);
           //UNamec=rs.getString(1);
           if(CNIC.equals(CNICc))
           {
               pageContext.forward("Hitchhiker-error.jsp");
           }
           else
           {
               ps.executeUpdate();
                pageContext.forward("Hitchhiker-success-register.jsp");
           }
       }


    %>
```

Comment: what issue are you are facing, ?

Comment: i cannot compare `CNIC` with `CNICc`. The CNIC is a local string while the CNICc is being fetched from the DB. The problem is in the bottom part of the code. Where the while loop is.

Comment: What do you mean by cannot compare, 
are you getting some error? 
or the code is running fine, but the CNIC and CNICc never match and the result is always false ?

Comment: Did the solution solve your problem? If not could you elaborate?

Comment: It is not getting matched.

Comment: Add a debug message and see what is actually getting matched. Updating answer. check and respond back with results

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand what you want me to do.

Comment: Just Rerun the updated code , It will print some values on console. Paste those values in comments.

Comment: From Result Set : a -comparing this with : 1310181490387From Result Set : muhammadahmad13@hotmail.com -comparing this with : 1310181490387From Result Set : muhammadahmad13@hotmail.com -comparing this with : 1310181490387From Result Set : muhammadahmad13@hotmail.com -comparing this with : 1310181490387From Result Set : muhammadahmad13@hotmail.com -comparing this with : 1310181490387

Comment: Read my comment on your Answer. I had to change the column index from 5 to 6 to get it to properly compare.

Comment: So do you see the problem ?

The result set value from column 5 is not gettting you id, and getting you email."
Do a rs.getString("cnnc")
Assuming cnnc is column name in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you may be facing is that the select * may return you n results and one of them may match.

Hence it will run the update once and create for rest of time.
You can modify it to:

```
 boolean isCNICFound = false;
 while(rs.next())
   {    


       CNICc=rs.getString(5);
       //out.println(CNIC);
       //UNamec=rs.getString(1)
           System.out.println("From Result Set : " + CNICc + " -comparing this with : " + CNIC);
           if(null != CNICc) {
               if(CNIC.equals(CNICc)) {
                  isCNICFound = true;
                   break;
                }
           }           
      }

if(isCNICFound ){
 pageContext.forward("Hitchhiker-error.jsp");
} else {
ps.executeUpdate();
                pageContext.forward("Hitchhiker-success-register.jsp");
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. The String from CNIC and CNICc is still not getting matched. I am using Workbench for a DB. i also tried the SQL command `Select * from CNIC` where i thought it should only look for the CNIC column but it didn't work aswel.

Comment: Print out the values what you are comparing, and see if you are picking up the valid columns from result set.

Comment: Well i found something weird. The index number of column i am using for `CNICc=rs.getString(5)` needs to be incremented once for the correct column eg `CNICc=rs.getString(6)`. Even then the string is getting matched. What i think the problem is that whenever the while loop is running if it even finds the first match in the DB it just forwards the page. Not checking the rest of the column.

Comment: two things :

1. Use break; ,see above code.
2. Use column name instead of position.

Suppose in database column name is "cnnc"
Do a   rs.getString("cnnc")

Answer (score 0):

One should close Connection, Statement and ResultSet. To do that automatically use try-with-resources as below.

Then on `SELECT *` a `rs.getString(5)` could pick the wrong column (there is no idea which columns will be listed);
either do `rs.getString("CNIC")` or better, do another query.

Also separate the statements, to close them well-behaved, even on errors.

After a `forward` better return so no more output is written to the browser.

```
    try (Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql1", "root", "")) {

        try (Statement s = c.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from hitchhikerdetails")) {

            while (rs.next()) {
                String CNICc = rs.getString("CNIC");
                if (CNIC.equals(CNICc)) {
                    pageContext.forward("Hitchhiker-error.jsp");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        try (PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(
                "insert into hitchhikerdetails(Uname,Name,Age,Address,CNIC)"
                + " values(?,?,?,?,?)")) {
            ps.setString(1, uname);
            ps.setString(2, name);
            ps.setString(3, age);
            ps.setString(4, address);
            ps.setString(5, CNIC);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            pageContext.forward("Hitchhiker-success-register.jsp");
            return;
        }
    }
```

To immediately query for a repeated CNIC:

```
        try (PreparedStatement s = c.prepareStatement(
                "select UName from hitchhikerdetails where CNIC = ?")) {
            s.setString(1, CNIC);
            try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    pageContext.forward("Hitchhiker-error.jsp");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out i had to increment the column index by 1 to get it to properly compare with the values. like `CNICc=rs.getstring(5)` was pointing towards the incorrect column which is strange because the value i am setting in the db from is the same index. But when i want to display the value i had to use an incremented index. like `CNICc=rs.getstring(6)`

Comment: Better `CNICc = rs.getString("CNIC");`; for `*` the column numbers are unclear.